# I can't wrap my head around the "draw some stairs with stick-men" program

Tags: java, for-loop

You've probably seen it before in a Java 1 class: it's a problem that asks you write a program that draws the following figure:

[image]

I have to use a constant. I am not allowed to use anything but for-loops, `print`, and `println`. No parameters, no arrays. I know how I could do it with parameters and arrays, lucky me. Any help is appreciated!

Here is my incomplete code:

```
public class Stairs {
    public static final int LENGTH=5;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printStairs();
    }

    public static void printStairs() {
        for (int allStairs=1; allStairs<=15; allStairs++) {
            for (int spaces=1; spaces<=(-5*allStairs+30); spaces++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (int stair = 1; stair <= 5; stair++) {
                System.out.println("  o  *******");

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This sounds like a homework question, so I don't just want to give you the answer, but try breaking it down into steps.  Think about the things that you know:

**1) Every stickman has this shape:**

```
  o  ******
 /|\ *     
 / \ *
```

**2) You can print this out using the following code:**

```
System.out.println("  o  ******");
System.out.println(" /|\ *     ");
System.out.println(" / \ *     ");
```

**3) You can print multiple by using a loop:**

```
for (int stair = 1; stair <= LENGTH; stair++) {
    System.out.println("  o  ******");
    System.out.println(" /|\ *     ");
    System.out.println(" / \ *     ");
}
```

Think about what kind of output this would give you, and what needs to be changed.  Realize that each stickman needs to be indented a certain amount.  Figure out how to indent them appropriately based on the value of `stair`.

Comment: You should probably remove the last line, each stickman has 3 lines for recursion purposes.

Comment: "Figure out how to modify the print statements to separate one stickman's stair from the next." / "If you repeat this, you will have duplicated stairs for each stickman. How can you change this to prevent that from happening?" Guess the cat's out of the bag :P

Comment: Thank you! I didn't want you to just give me the answer either, I actually want to understand it.

Comment: @JonathanNewmuis: Sorry, missed that line. :) I liked everything about your answer except that part though, I think putting the 4th line in there added more confusion than it might help with understanding. Still, a nice explanation.

Comment: For some reason, I can't paste my modified code in here and have it look neat, but anyway, I have it where I need it to print the stairs and stickmen with the right indentations. I just have to finish the back part. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Keppil Removed.  I'd rather the answer be too transparent than too confusing.

Answer (score 4):

You can look at the figure and observe that each stickman has 3 lines, for each line:

- Spaces, if necessary, proportionate to the number of stickmen
- Part of the stick man - you can hard code this
- The flat surface of 6 `*`, or one `*` followed by 5 spaces
- Spaces, if necessary, proportionate to the number of stickmen
- A `*`

And at the end, the last line is `*` proportionate to the number of stickmen.

Comment: I am having trouble writing the expression for the first nested loop (the one that prints just spaces). It kind of works, but I have a lot of extra, unneeded lines.

Comment: 1) You can see that the amount of space is multiple of 5. 2) Compare the case where number stickmen `n` is one less or one more, you will be able to see that the first line will always have `n` - 1 groups of spaces. 3) Compare within the figure, the next line will have 1 less group of spaces.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my final final attempt using [formatting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int steps = 5;
    for (int x = 0; x < steps; x++) {
        System.out.format(((steps == (x + 1)) ? "" : ("%"
                + ((steps - x - 1) * 5) + "s"))
                + "  o  ******"
                + ((x == 0) ? "" : ("%" + (x * 5) + "s"))
                + "*\n", " ", " ");
        System.out.format(((steps == (x + 1)) ? "" : ("%"
                + ((steps - x - 1) * 5) + "s"))
                + " /|\\ *     "
                + ((x == 0) ? "" : ("%" + (x * 5) + "s"))
                + "*\n", " ", " ");
        System.out.format(((steps == (x + 1)) ? "" : ("%"
                + ((steps - x - 1) * 5) + "s"))
                + " / \\ *     "
                + ((x == 0) ? "" : ("%" + (x * 5) + "s"))
                + "*\n", " ", " ");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < (steps + 1) * 5 + 2; i++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
                      o  *******
                     /|\ *     *
                     / \ *     *
                 o  ******     *
                /|\ *          *
                / \ *          *
            o  ******          *
           /|\ *               *
           / \ *               *
       o  ******               *
      /|\ *                    *
      / \ *                    *
  o  ******                    *
 /|\ *                         *
 / \ *                         *
********************************
```

\o/

The approach below is also funny (depending on your humor preferences), but not a complete solution:

```
    for (String s = "                           o  *****                          /|\\ *                              / \\ *    "; s
            .charAt(8) != '*'; s = s.substring(5, s.length() / 3) + "     "
            + s.substring(s.length() / 3 + 5, 2 * s.length() / 3) + "     "
            + s.substring(2 * s.length() / 3 + 5, s.length()) + "     ") {
        System.out.println(s.substring(0, s.length() / 3) + "*");
        System.out
                .println(s.substring(s.length() / 3, 2 * (s.length() / 3))
                        + "*");
        System.out.println(s.substring(2 * (s.length() / 3), s.length())
                + "*");
    }
```

Output:

```
                       o  ******
                      /|\ *    *
                      / \ *    *
                  o  *****     *
                 /|\ *         *
                 / \ *         *
             o  *****          *
            /|\ *              *
            / \ *              *
        o  *****               *
       /|\ *                   *
       / \ *                   *
   o  *****                    *
  /|\ *                        *
  / \ *                        *
```

Comment: Note that the O.P. said "no parameters", which we're interpreting to mean "no methods other than `main()`.

Comment: Ernest, thanks for the heads up. Removed the method (it wasn't essential) and finally worked out how to do this with formatting. Too bad I need conditionals to avoid zero width parameters.

Answer (score 2):

There is a recursive block with diminishing white space. The recursion ends at `LEFT_SPACE == 0` The recursive block is

```
LEFT_SPACE o  ******RIGHT_SPACE*
LEFT_SPACE/|\ *     RIGHT_SPACE*
LEFT_SPACE/ \ *     RIGHT_SPACE*
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some tips:

- You should think about it horizontally.
- your main loop must be stairs amount related because you are bound by the number of stairs you have to draw.
- It will probably be easiest to print each line separately, so understand all the information you need to draw each line.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ultimately ended up with:

```
public class Stairs {
    public static final int LENGTH=5;

    // The 'main method' prints out all the stairs with the appropriate indentations.
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // outer loop
        for (int allStairs=0; allStairs<=4; allStairs++) {
            // first nested loops print the heads and tops of steps
            for (int spaces=1; spaces<=(-5*allStairs+20); spaces++) {
                printSpace();
            }
            System.out.print("  o  ******");
            for (int backWall=0; backWall<allStairs*(LENGTH); backWall++) {
                printSpace();
            }
            printStar();
            // second nexted loops print the body and the backs of the stairs
            for (int spaces = 1; spaces <= (-5 * allStairs + 20); spaces++) {
                printSpace();
            }
            System.out.print(" /|\\ *");
            for (int backWall=1; backWall<=LENGTH*(allStairs+1); backWall++) {
                printSpace();
            }
            printStar();
            // third nested loops print the legs and lower backs of stairs
            for (int spaces = 1; spaces <= (-5 * allStairs + 20); spaces++) {
                printSpace();
            }
            System.out.print(" / \\ *");
            for (int backWall=1; backWall<=LENGTH*(allStairs+1); backWall++) {
                printSpace();
            }
            printStar();
        }
        // this loop prints the very bottom line of stars
        for (int lastLine=1; lastLine<=32; lastLine++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    // printSpace() prints out a space
    public static void printSpace() {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }

    // printStar() prints out an asterisk
    public static void printStar() {
        System.out.println("*");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it looks horribly redundant, but I couldn't put the loops into new methods because of variable scope. When I ran it in Eclipse, though, it looked like the drawing I was given with. Thank you to everyone who helped me, and I'm very interested to see if I still could have condensed this more.

Comment: Just for laughs take a look at my answer. Might not fulfill the assignment since it uses conditionals but nice and compact (and unreadable).

Comment: I really like yours because of how compact it is. Too bad I couldn't have done something similar. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I did it slightly differently. The following script will work with any number of stairs.  I've commented it so you should know exactly what I am doing.

```
public class stairman {

//establishing class constants
public static final int STAIR_NUM = 5;
public static final int WIDTH = STAIR_NUM * 5;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //perform this loop for as many times as there are stairs
    for (int i=1; i<=STAIR_NUM; i++) { 

        //calculating number of spaces before the top line of the stair
        for (int x=1; x<=(WIDTH+(i*(-5))); x++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        //printing top line of the stair
        head();

        //calculating the number of spaces after the top line of the stair
        for(int y=1; y<=((i-1)*5); y++){ 
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println("*");

        //calculating the number of spaces before the 1st middle line of the stair
        for (int x=1; x<=(WIDTH+(i*(-5))); x++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        //print the first middle line of the stair
        middle1();

        //calculating the number of spaces after the 1st middle line of the stair           
        for (int y=1; y<=(i*5); y++){ 
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println("*");

        //calculating the number of spaces before the 2nd middle line of the stair          
        for (int x=1; x<=(WIDTH+(i*(-5))); x++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        //printing the 2nd middle line of the stair
        middle2();

      //calculating the number of spaces after the 2nd middle line of the stair
        for (int y=1; y<=(i*5); y++){ 
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println("*");
    }

    //calculating the number of stars needed for the bottom of the stairs
    for (int z=1; z<=(WIDTH+7); z++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
}

public static void head() {
    System.out.print("  o  ******");
}
public static void middle1() {
        System.out.print(" /|\\ *");
}
public static void middle2() {
    System.out.print(" / \\ *");
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

I tested the above code and it wasn't working for me. So I had a go at it and used some of their ideas.

```
public class DrawStairs {   

public static final int HEIGHT= 5;

public static final int TOTALHEIGHT= HEIGHT*5;

public static void main(String[] args){
    //Main Outer Loop
    for(int i=1; i<=HEIGHT; i++){

        //Loop for the spaces before, then print the head
        for(int j=1; j<=TOTALHEIGHT+(i*(-5)); j++){ 
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        printTop();

        //Loop for spaces after, then print asterisk
        for(int j=1; j<=(i-1)*5; j++){ 
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println("*");

        //Loop for the spaces before, then print the body
        for(int j=1; j<=TOTALHEIGHT+(i*(-5)); j++){ 
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        printMiddle();

        //Loop for spaces after, then print asterisk
        for(int j=1; j<=(i-1)*5; j++){ 
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println("*");

        //Loop for spaces before, then print the legs
        for(int j=1; j<=TOTALHEIGHT+(i*(-5)); j++){ 
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        printBottom();

        //Loop for spaces after, then print asterisk
        for(int j=1; j<=(i-1)*5; j++){ 
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println("*");            
    }

    // for loop for printing the floor of asterisks
    for(int i=1; i<= TOTALHEIGHT+7; i++){
        System.out.print("*");
    }
}   

public static void printTop() {
    System.out.print("  o  ******");
}

public static void printMiddle() {
    System.out.print(" /|\\ *     ");
}

public static void printBottom() {
    System.out.print(" / \\ *     ");
}
}
```

Comment: What needs explanation? It is a very complex explanation to explain everything.. If you copy and paste it and run it, even change the HEIGHT constant to anything >5 it will work perfectly.

Comment: I reviewed your answer and I suggested you to improve your answer by adding some explanations.